# How to assign an image texture to multiple faces with python API?

Tags: python

As shown in the screenshot below,
I assign an image texture to the multiple faces with mouse,
But I need to do it with python API, how to do it?
[image]

Comment: You cannot assign textures to faces in current versions. You assign faces to material slots, then materials to material slots and then use textures in materials. You can do that with Python, but you need to do everything in the way you would manually - create material slot, material and use a texture in it.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys: are you sure he doesn't mean that "assign" button which at least "give the feeling" of assigning faces to a material?

Comment: @Chris Might be.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I use "assign" button to do it. or another way is ok, I rewrite it  in a new question.

Comment: @zwl1619 please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/289104/edit) the question and rewrite it here. Please also explain in more detail what you mean, what you need this for and all the context of the question. What are you trying to achieve here? The more information you provide, the better the chances for you to get good answers.